# Need to view merged photos directory in date sequence

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I have two photo folders taken with different cameras, and want to merge them by date, and then view the combined directory in date sequence.  I have merged them, and the directory dates look good, but the tools I use insist of showing the photos in name sequence, which is not what I want.  I thought of doing a batch rename function to make the date part of the file names, using a `bat` file, but the `DOS DIR` command doesn't seem to use this date - if I do

```
for /f "skip=5 tokens=1,2,4,5* delims= " %%i in ('dir /a:-d /o:d /t:c') do (
```

etc., most of the file dates are correct, but some of the files seem to be using the "created date" of the *directory*.

Maybe there is a simple solution as this must be a common problem, but I haven't found a good solution - short of doing a laborious manual rename of some 700+ files!

Help would be appreciated!

Paul M.

Comment: you need the date/time from EXIF data. `Batch` can't read EXIF data. But there are utilities out there which can. Google for `rename by exif date`

Comment: Thanks, Stephan.  That did the trick!

Answer (score 0):

```
for /f "tokens=1*delims=[]" %%a in ('dir /b /a-d /od /t:c^|find /v /n "" ') do echo ren "%%b" "%%a%%~xb"
```

Perform a directory scan of the source directory, in `/b` basic mode `/a-d` without directories in date order selecting created-date, number in brackets each line that doesn't match an empty string and assign each filename found to `%%b` and the number to `%%a`

The required REN commands are merely `ECHO`ed for testing purposes. **After you've verified that the commands are correct**, change `ECHO REN` to `REN` to actually rename the files.

Note: filenames that begin `[` or `]` will be processed incorrectly. If an existing file has a name which belongs to the target nameset (ie 1.? 2.? etc.) then simply prefix the target name with a prefix that doesn't already exist, eg `ren "%%b" "new_%%a%%~xb"` (where  there are no existing files named `new_*`)

---

I'm not sure about Win7's capability when displaying files using the utility you are using (Explorer?) Win10 has the capability of selecting display by creation-date (select `sort by` then creation-date)

If you are sure you are sorting by creation-date then probably you'd need to select some other sorting scheme (change `t:c` to `t` perhaps)

If there are filenames that aren't being converted, then you are probably adding files (called img*) to a directory that already contains files named 1,2,3... - in fact, it's difficult to see how that phenomenon could happen otherwise.

Change `"%%a%%~xb"` in the `rename` command to `"xyz%%a%%~xb"` and you should find that the files are then all renamed xyz1,xyz2,xyz3 etc. If you then reprocess the files with `xyz` removed, the names should become 1,2,3 with no omissions.

Comment: Hi Magoo, many thanks for your solution - much simpler than mine, although it contains some very mysterious `DOS` syntax!  Unfortunately, it suffers from the same problems as my solution: 1) the date sequence is still different from that displayed by Win7, and 2) some files remain unconverted.  I have put two screen grabs up at http://www.jpaulmorrison.com/prob1.jpg and http://www.jpaulmorrison.com/prob2.jpg , resp.  Any thoughts?  Anyone else? TIA

Comment: Turned out that Stephan's answer was the right one - worked like a charm!